# How can I use a Bundle Transform to write a wrapper to the bundle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to write a custom transform for script bundles that wraps some JS around all the files in the bundle. I researched the `IBundleTransform` interface and I know that I can add a Transform like the following to any bundle:

```
public class CustomTransformType : IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        string bundleResponse = string.Empty;
        foreach (FileInfo file in response.Files)
        {
            // PROCESS FILE CONTENT 
        }
        response.Content = bundleResponse;
    }
}
```

However, this puts the onus on me to stream all the files into one string buffer which I can then wrap with my own code.

I was wondering if there was a way to get the resulting bundle file and use *THAT* for my wrapper? So, instead, do something like:

```
public class CustomTransformType : IBundleTransform
{
    private string wrapBeg = "(function () {";
    private string wrapEnd = "})";

    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        string bundleResponse = wrapBeg + response.Bundle + wrapEnd;

    }
}
```

The above code is an illustration of what I want to do, not an implementation.

If the above is not available, can anyone suggest a good way to stream the files and some gotchas I should look out for?

Comment: What version of .net are you on?

Comment: I'm on version 4.5

Comment: My hunch is that doing this in .net core would actually be fairly straightforward as you could just write a custom gulp function for it.  Here is the documentation for bundling in 4.5 https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification if it helps.